# Reading URL from a console and printing it in textarea in GUI

Tags: java, swing

I am working on project "Distributed Web Crawler using Java RMI".
The web crawls the pages and displays the URLs on two consoles-- a client one and a server one.
My problem is that I have to read these URLs from the console and display it under a Text Area in a window. I have tried a lot but the URLs are not getting displayed in Text Area.
However they were getting displayed on the console.

My code is:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.File;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class UCDemo implements ActionListener {
    static String dispServerURL;
    JFrame f1;
    JPanel p1;
    JLabel l1;
    JLabel l2;
    JTextField t1;
    JTextArea t2;
    JButton b1;

    public void showFrame() {
        f1 = new JFrame("Web Crawler");
        p1 = new JPanel();
        f1.setSize(7000, 7000);
        f1.setVisible(true);
        f1.setBackground(Color.pink);
        f1.getContentPane().add(p1);
        l1 = new JLabel("Enter seed URL");
        t1 = new JTextField(100);
        b1 = new JButton("Start");
        l2 = new JLabel("Result");
        t2 = new JTextArea(200, 200);

        p1.add(l1);
        p1.add(t1);
        p1.add(b1);
        p1.add(l2);
        p1.add(t2);

        b1.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        try {
            DispServerIntf dispServerIntf = (DispServerIntf) Naming.lookup(dispServerURL);
            if (ae.getSource() == b1) {
                String n1, k;
                InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
                n1 = t1.getText();
                int c = 0;
                Document document = null;
                URL hp = new URL(n1);
                URLConnection hpcon = hp.openConnection();

                try {
                    document = Jsoup.parse(hp, 3000);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                for (Element element : document.getElementsByTag("a")) {
                    c++;
                    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(hp.openStream());
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("te.html");
                    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
                    if (c <= 7) {
                        Document doc_tmp = null;
                        URL hp_tmp = new URL(element.attr("href"));
                        t2.setText("" + hp_tmp);
                        URLConnection hpcontmp = hp_tmp.openConnection();
                        /**
                         * try { doc_tmp=Jsoup.parse(hp_tmp,3000); }
                         * catch(IOException e) {e.printStackTrace(); } for
                         * (Element ele: doc_tmp.getElementsByTag("a")) {
                         * System.out.println(ele.attr("href")); }
                         **/
                        ReadableByteChannel rbc_tmp = Channels.newChannel(hp_tmp.openStream());
                        FileOutputStream fos_tmp = new FileOutputStream("te" + c + ".html");
                        fos_tmp.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc_tmp, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);

                    } else {
                        dispServerIntf.send(element.attr("href"));
                    }
                }
                /**
                 * BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new
                 * InputStreamReader(hpcon.getInputStream())); String inputline;
                 * while((inputline=in.readLine())!=null)
                 * System.out.println(inputline); in.close();
                 **/
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        dispServerURL = "rmi://" + args[0] + "/DispServer";

        new UCDemo().showFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to explain in more detail, and add more relevant code (ideally a compilable, runnable example, see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)), before anyone is likely to be able to help with this.

Comment: Please format your code properly if you want people to take the trouble to read it - I have edited the question and done this for you here.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you are doing all the work in a loop on the AWT thread (the "event dispatch thread") within the `actionPerformed` method, and updating the GUI in that loop.

This means that the GUI will not be updated properly (because the thread that updates the GUI is busy doing the HTML parsing work, and does not become free to process GUI events). You probably need to do the main loop in a separate thread, then update the GUI in the AWT thread using `invokeLater()`.

See:

- [this tutorial](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml), for example,
- and the linked introduction to [threading in Swing](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/swing_ui.shtml).
- The official [Swing Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) on this topic, which assumes you have read...
- ...the [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) lesson

Also, you always set the text to a single value, so you would only see the latest URL, not a list of them:

```
t2.setText("" + hp_tmp);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code editing and your valuable guidance. I will try to improve upon it and will be discussing it further...:)

Comment: I read the tutorial. I was not able to gain much from it as I have little knowledge about java.

Comment: I have added further tutorial links - understanding the threading model is vital for writing Swing applications that do any work in the background.